# Making an app similar to toilet finder

Tags: iphone, google-maps, gps

I want to make an app similar to toilet finder...

The way i think is that , i will show all the bathrooms near device on my own map

but don't know how and where to find the database...

i googled and found some links like [this](http://www.publictoilets.org/pt) but don't know how to get data from them......

I think google can provide me this but how to get?

Help please....

Answer (score 0):

You could search for an API for that purpose.. A Toilet API, or you could load the complete database on your app and get the info you need from that database or XML.. Depends on what you want to do.. It is possible that no API exists and that you have to get a database somewhere..

Comment: i already have searched (before asking question)  for api but not found ...so i start working on second path..but still not getting database required